# How to continue execution after returning in .net core api

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a method that processes a large file for updates to a data source. This process can potentially take a long time to run depending on the size of the file and the complexity of the changes required.

I would like to kick off the processing of the file and then return a status code of 200 to the caller letting them know that the file was successfully uploaded.

The goal would then be to send the user who uploaded the file an email letting them know that the file has been processed, and it would include any information, such as individual rows that could not be processed because they failed data validation checks.

I tried to simply not await the processing of the file

```cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReorderController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFromFile(IFormFile csv)
    {
        ParseCSVAsync(csv);
        return Ok();
    }

    private async Task ParseCSVAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        // file processing code
    }
}
```

But when the action returns the Ok status code, the resources get disposed of, and the execution stops before the processing is complete.

Is there some .net core lifecycle I can hook into to be able to do this processing of the file outside of the HTTP request that starts it?

Comment: This kind of thing gets asked a lot. Did you do much research? You just need a separate background service set to run at frequent intervals. The Web API would simply save the file, then write some data somewhere (e.g. maybe a database table) telling the service that a job is ready for it. Next time the service runs it will see the new job and process it, and can send an email when it's finished.

Comment: Or you might be able to use something like [HangFire](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html) to produce a similar effect all within your ASP.NET application. But you certainly can't do what you're asking with the basic context of an API request - once you return a value to the client, the request always ends.